# Angular 2 ngrx : how to update an array which is embedded in one the the items of my state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, redux, ngrx

In my reducer, i would like to add an element which is in an array like this :

**The JSON structure (recieved with http services):**

```
{
 "id": "09fabf9a-e532-4d2a-87cc-bd949a0a437f",
 "title": 'my title',
 "itemId": "6d442772-d414-46b1-8aab-a105d2bc3b38",
 "createdOn": "2017-01-12T10:12:22.987Z",
 **"replays": []**
}
```

So I would like to add (and why not update) this **replays** array, wich is in the reviews array.

**REVIEWS ARRAY :**

```
[review1,review2,review3...review(n)]
```

I already have a reducer for managing the reviews, but how would I do it with ***replays*** the redux way ? 
THX

**EDIT 1 : REDUCER CODE**

```
xport const Reviews: ActionReducer<Array<Review>> = (state: any[] = [], action: Action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_REVIEWS:
        return action.payload;
    case ADD_REVIEW:
        return [...state, action.payload];
    case UPDATE_REVIEW:
        let index = state.map(review => review.id).indexOf(action.payload.id);
        return [
            ...state.slice(0, index),
            Object.assign({}, state[index], action.payload),
            ...state.slice(index + 1)
        ];
    case DELETE_REVIEW:
        return state.filter(item => {
            return item.id !== action.payload;
        });
    case ADD_REPLAY:
       return 'HERE I'AM STUCK !'
    default:
        return state;
}
```

};

Comment: Could you add your reducer code as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your action for the `ADD_REPLAY` action is an object with the review's ID plus the Replay to add. In order to not mutate the objects (replay and review) you have to replace them.

```
case ADD_REPLAY:
    let index = state.map(review => review.id).indexOf(action.payload.id);
    return [
        ...state.slice(0, index),
        Object.assign({}, state[index], {
            replays: [...state[index].replays, action.payload.replay]
        }),
        ...state.slice(index + 1)
    ];
```

There's a great free video explaining how to avoid array mutations on [egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread).

Comment: Great video, it's short and sweet. I recommend future readers check it out!